# CMD: Sleep and hit any key, at the same time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sleep

i have this batch file, which makes constantly a loop. I want the user to be able to terminate it in the batch, not just clicking the X.

This is what i need (somehow):

```
@echo off
:proc
cls
rem All kind of stuff...
echo Hit any key to terminate...
sleep 1
@pause>nul
```

But, of course, sleep and pause can't work at the same time.

How ***is*** it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the pause and change the message to "Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to terminate". Presumably the script has a "goto :proc" that you are not showing?

Comment: Yeah, but then, it asks if i'm sure; i don't want that.

Comment: I don't think there is any way of avoiding this message - certainly many of the suggested fixes I've seen like using the "start" command don't work. IMHO, the best solution, if it is possible for you, is to switch to a better command interpreter, such as MSYS bash.

Comment: The problem is, that it is not possible. Isn't it possible, on VBScript, or so?

Answer (score 3):

More recent editions of Windows has the TIMEOUT command that does just this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754891%28v=ws.10%29.aspx